# How can I catch the width of select2 dropdown?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropdown, with 100% width to its container. The container width is variable.
My dropdown has the correct width. But when I select an option with a long name, the size of the dropdown increases. I tried many things to prevent this. But nothing is working because I cannot use a fixed size.

So my approach is to capture the size of of the select2, before I select the option and and then after selecting the option add the same size to the select box again. But trying to catch the width of the select box is not working.

```
$(document).on('change', '.select2', function(e) {
    var width = $( this ).css( "width" );
    alert(width);
  });
```

The output is `1px` but the size is definitely wider than 1px.

https://jsfiddle.net/d5w8t36m/1/

Comment: Can you provide an example where it's changing the size of the select2?  Your fiddle on a small screen wraps the value in the drop down and truncates (`...`) the value when selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` in this case, is actually the selected item **not** the select dropdown. To do get the select dropdown, call the parent then `width()`

```js
$(document).on('change', '.select2', function(e) {
    var width = $(this).parent().width();
    alert(width);
});
```